# AWS Configure Tomcat's virtual directory and emailing system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm deploying my first application on AWS and there are a couple of things I just cannot find a solution for.

1.**File system**

The application is using Lucene and allows image uploading, therefore I'm guessing I need an S3 instance to host the Lucene index and the images.

For testing purposes, on my local system I would place this line of code in Tomcat 7's `server.xml`:

`<Context path="/uploads" docBase="D:/myapp/uploads" />`. Now, as you probably know, all the requests starting with `/uploads` would be routed to `D:/myapp/uploads` by the server.

Furthermore, the Lucene API needs a absolute path in order to find the Index Directory:

```
FSDirectory.open(new File(ConfigUtil.getProperty("D:/myapp/index")))
```

My first question is about this configuration in the AWS Console. How can I obtain those `D:/aaa/bbb/' paths?

2.**Emailing system**

After registration, a confirmation email is sent to the user. Again, in testing I used Google's `smtp.gmail.com`. I would need a **host** a **username** and a **password** to make the javax.mail API work.

I have no idea how can I obtain those credentials? Is it a AWS matter or a Domain Registrar (I'm using namecheap) matter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. It is totally unclear what you actually want. Also add a bit more information which services you are trying to use on AWS. Concerning emails, aws is not a full-service-webspace provider and thus does not offer email accounts

Answer (score 0):

To host the images on S3, you have two options.

Either allow upload to an [EBS-backed EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) first, as you did on your test system, and move them to S3 afterwards asynchronously.
In this case, you can choose any path you wish on the EBS volume to temporarily store the uploaded files.

Or modify your front-end to allow submission to S3 directly.

Likewise, you can choose any path you wish on the EBS volume to store Lucene's index.

Regarding the use of javax.mail

1. set `smtp.gmail.com` as host
2. create a gmail account
3. use the newly created account's `username` and `password`